# Rotation Graph, Maximum and Minimum Slope

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

I apologize for the last question, it is my first post so I will try to edit this better. The problem is:

The graph of $f(x) = -7x + e^{3x-50x^2}$ is rotated counterclockwise about the origin through an acute angle $\theta$. What is the largest value of $\theta$ for which the rotated graph is still the graph of a function? What about if the graph is rotated clockwise?

---

First derivative: $-7+e^{3x-50x^2}(3-100x)$

Second Derivative: $10000e^{-50x^2+3x}x^2 - 600e^{-50x^2+3x}x-91e^{-50x^2+3x}$

Setting second derivative equal to $0$: $x_1= -7/100$, $x_2=13/100$

The interval from negative infinity to $-7/100$ is positive, the interval from $-7/100$ to $13/100$ is negative and the interval from $13/100$ to positive infinity is positive.

I evaluated the first derivative with the value $-7/100$ and got: $-7+10/e^{91/200}$ or the decimal representation of $-0.65552$)

I evaluated the first derivative with the value $13/100$ and got: $-7-10/e^{91/200}$ or the decimal representation of $-13.34447$)

Comment: Can you show us what you found for $f''(x)=0$? Details are more helpful than just the general idea that you used.

Comment: Thank you I understand, but after you input them into the first derivative which is the slope of the function, you get the value of the maximum or minimum slope dependent on the value input (negative or positive).

Comment: Yes, I got -7/100 & 13/100 for the solution of the second derivative equaled to zero. I input -7/100 to the first derivative and get an expression which I will write the decimal representation of it: -0.66 which I believe it is supposed to be the maximum slope?

Comment: These $x$-values do not satisfy $f''(x)=0$. If you could, please edit the question to include the steps you went through to find these values. We can likely find the error from there :)

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Are you sure about these derivatives? The original function is $f(x)=-2x + e^{5x-8x^2}$, so you should get, for example, $f'(x)=-2+e^{5x-8x^2}(5-16x)$.

Comment: Oh, now I see the problem, I set the function in the beginning wrong, I apologize, here I reset it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you have written is correct up to this point. We have a maximum slope of $$m=f'\left(-\frac{7}{100}\right)=-7+10e^{-\frac{91}{200}}\approx-0.65552.$$

Now, we want to convert this slope into an angle, so that we can rotate it. To do this, we solve for $\alpha$ is $\tan\alpha=m$. Doing this gives us $\alpha\approx -33.2^\circ$. Therefore, we can rotate $\alpha$ counter-clockwise up to $\sim123.2^\circ$, since any more than that would give us a vertical slope. So, this would be $\theta$ (however, the problem says that $\theta$ is acute? Double-check that).

Going the other way, we have a minimum slope of $$m=f'\left(\frac{13}{100}\right)=-7-10e^{-\frac{91}{200}}\approx-13.34448.$$

We solve for $\alpha$ in $\tan\alpha=m$. Doing this gives us $\alpha\approx -85.7^\circ$. We can rotate $\alpha$ clockwise up to $\sim4.3^\circ$, since any more than that would give us a vertical slope. So $\theta\approx 4.3^\circ$.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your time. This is why I posed the question in the first point, even though I input those results, it still highlights them as incorrect. https://query.libretexts.org/Community_Gallery/WeBWorK_Assessments/Calculus_-_single_variable/Differentiation/Derivatives_of_exponential_functions/prob23a.pg. Is the website evaluation wrong or we're doing something wrong?

Comment: I strongly suspect that the site is incorrect. The slopes here are certainly correct.

Comment: I think so as well, thank you for your time though, you have been very helpful.

Comment: Should I post it as a different question describing the problem and maybe we can confirm if the site evaluation is incorrect?

Comment: You don't need to. There is an error in the question to begin with; that is, I don't think they intended to actually have the function be $f(x)=-7x + e^{3x-50x^2}$. Just looking at the graph of this function, you can tell that the function can be rotated by more than $90^\circ$ and still be a function, so the restriction on $\theta$ being acute does not make sense to begin with. A better option would be to contact the site owners directly.

Comment: Will do, thank you.